# need to display an HTML page in react native app and implement a text search in the HTML page content, please advise

Tags: react-native

Need to display html page content in react native app and also need to implement a text search on the html page content, please advise

in HTML: I added a text box and search button on top of the html page in a floating div and added text searching js function in the  tag

React Native App: added react native html viewer library to load the html page content in the webview

HTML text contents are showing but the text input box and search button are not showing, also js functions are not executing

Answer (score 0):

You can use react native web view and load the html page with it.
You should enable java script by changing the web view props:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://example.example.com'}}
        javascriptenabled={true} />
    );
  }
```

For more details - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview